# Qt Кнопка сохранить как и открыть(ошибка и запоминание)

Tags: qt

Как сделать так, что бы кнопки сохранить и открыть запомнили последний файл? А также, что бы кнопка открыть не видила закрытые папки(серый оттенок имеют, на картинке увидите, просто не помню как это называется) и вот тут есть ошибка, как её решить? - https://yadi.sk/i/r6vXOXd63Ji8kA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` и `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName`, то в качестве одного из параметров можете передать путь к директории, которая будет открыта в диалоговом окне. (Да и вообще у `QFileDialog` есть такой параметр) А вот уже откуда взять этот путь - решать вам.
Например, можете использовать `QSettings` и хранить в ini-файле пути к последним открытым файлам. Заодно сможете добавить пункт в меню или кнопку "Последние открытые".